# Black screen in Ubuntu 17.10 on HP Pavilllion 15 ab125ax

Tags: 17.10, amd-graphics, hp-pavilion

I installed Ubuntu 17.10 on my HP Pavilllion 15 ab125ax system and while installation, the screen went black after booting from a usb stick. I read about it online and installed it after using the "nomodeset"  to bypass the drivers. After installing when I boot into the system, the screen goes blank after some random time. 
System Specifications
Product Name    15-ab125ax
Microprocessor  1.8 GHz AMD Quad-Core A10-8700P APU with Radeon R6 Graphics
Microprocessor Cache    2 MB cache
Memory  8 GB DDR3L SDRAM (1 x 8 GB)
Video Graphics  AMD Radeon R7 M360 Graphics (2 GB DDR3 dedicated

Is it that my graphics card is not compatible with the OS? Any solutions for this problem?